# Any way to compress video with AWS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way to support reducing video size while uploading video files to `AWS S3 bucket`?

I tried `Lambda` service provided by AWS. I downloaded video file from the input bucket and used `ffmpeg` to compress the video file. But there is only 512MB space limit in `tmp` folder which is only writable folder in Lambda and 512MB is not enough for my work.

Anyone has ideas to figure out this?

Answer (score 10):

There are two AWS services that might assist:

The [Amazon Elastic Transcoder service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html) lets you convert media files stored in Amazon S3. For example, you can convert large, high-quality digital media files into formats that users can play back on mobile devices, tablets, web browsers, and connected televisions.

The [AWS Elemental MediaConvert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/what-is.html) is a file-based video processing service that provides scalable video processing for content owners and distributors with media libraries of any size.

These will not convert "while uploading". Rather, they will **transcode videos** already stored in Amazon S3 and will save the results back to S3. To reduce the storage size of a video, you would need to change some attributes (eg dimensions, quality, encoding method) that would result in a smaller file.