# Video and image compression before uploading to s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-compression, image-size

i am making an application in which i want to upload videos and images to s3 bucket from my application written in java. Can somebody suggest me some library provided by java to do so. I want to compress them in such a way like whatsapp do no need to uncompress them

Comment: Amazon S3 stores whatever data you pass to it. If you wish to modify videos and images, you'll need to do that outside of Amazon S3. AWS Lambda functions are good for resizing images. Videos are a lot harder — I like to use Amazon Elastic Transcoder, which can take a video from S3, re-encode it and store it back into S3. That's good for changing the size and quality.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can leverage some AWS services like

1. [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html)
2. [AWS Elemental MediaConvert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/what-is.html)

For compression the media.

Also, I would encourage you to look at the [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) for resizing the images using lambda.

Comment: do above these provide any libraries in java to compress them before uploading

Comment: AWS provides sdk and apis to do the compression using their service. But these are not libraries that can do the compression locally. It will compress in cloud and then the compressed file can be uploaded.

Comment: ok so aws lambda could be used for resizing images but what about videos?

Comment: I haven't used it to encode videos but I think it might be possible. I would like you to look at the blog :  https://medium.com/@federicopanini/video-content-generated-solution-with-aws-lambda-ccb5d5d4629c

Comment: Note that these solutions do not convert the files while uploading them, but rather transcode files already stored on your S3 bucket as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037201/any-way-to-compress-video-with-aws-service

Comment: Serverless Image Handler doesn't compress, so files beyond 6MB. Oops. Lambda limits